# Why not able to use await in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Using `await` here, get an error if I remove it it works. But hey, it is from a how-to.

`const posts = await graph.fetch('523008607856853', 'posts', 5)`

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only use await inside a [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

**Will not work:**

```
function notAsync () {
 await aPromise()
}
```

**Will Work:**

```
async function isAsync() {
 await aPromise()
}
```

**Example with arrow function**

```
const isAsync = async () => {
 await aPromise()
}
```

Comment: Hi! What if function is defined like this? `responseFacebook = response => {`

Comment: If you mean an arrow function? I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the function as an `async` function before you can await a promise.

In this case, `componentDidMount()` needs to be `async componentDidMount()` and you should be good to go.

Also, in case your promise is rejected, be sure to wrap the `await` in a `try/catch` so you can see the error:

```
async componentDidMount() {...


try {
  const posts = await graph.fetch('523008607856853', 'posts', 5)
} catch (error) {
  console.log('error fetching graph', error);
}
```

Hope this helps!