# Members Cache only has me and a bot in it even though I have server members intents

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So I'm making a server info command which needs a member list. I used guild.members.cache.map.lengh but it only returned 2. I tried to trouble shoot it with looking at the collection itself but I only saw myself and the bot. I searched for the issue and found one but the writer just said "its just intents problem" so I turned the member intent on and added GUILD_MEMBERS to my intents but still doesn't work. Can someone tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Use `await guild.members.fetch()` right above it

Comment: Ok I was only looking at the cache but now I'll also try the fetch() and list() functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cache is unreliable. You can instead [`fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch) the members from the API

```js
const members = await guild.members.fetch()
console.log(members.size) //should output correct result
```

Comment: It gives me undefined. Also await will give me "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules".

Comment: Make sure the function is `async`. You can do this by putting `async` before the function parameters (only if it's unnamed) or in front of the name (if it is named)

Comment: Also how do I know what functions use await?

Comment: Here's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58770756/15781079) that may help you  better understand

Comment: Also see [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)